# How to create RealmSchema for using production realm in instrumentation test?

Tags: android, realm, realm-java

I want to debug an issue that might only happen on certain data.
Therefore I want to use a specific Realm file in an AndroidTest.

However, I get the `RealmMigrationNeededException` and can't add the classes to a module manually since I get an error saying that I can only add classes from this project. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        java.srcDir 'src/main/java'
    }
}
```

Adding this to my `build.gradle` fixed the problem. I suspect it is not without side-effects, but it worked.